# I have created projects in Selenium and Watir but when I am executing feature file along my_steps.rb then it shows the errors with concrete actions

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rubymine

```
**Google_Visit.feature**

Feature: Navigating Google By Cucumber
  I want to navigate to Google.com

  Scenario: Visiting Google
    Given I am on Google.com Page

**google_steps.rb**

Given(/^I am on Google\.com Page$/) do
  @browser = Selenium :: Browser.start(SITE, :firefox)
  @browser.goto(PAGES["http://www.google.com"])
end

**feature/support/env.rb**

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'

SITE = 'www.google.com'
Browser = Selenium :: Browser.start(SITE, :firefox)
PAGES = {
    "Google Home" => "www.google.com",
}
```

I have tried much time but only the errors showing in Result section:

*You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

```
Given(/^I am on Google\.com Page$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
1 scenario (1 undefined)
1 step (1 undefined)
0m0.021s*
```

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - and then, think of making title of question crisper and don't use it for complete question.

Comment: Do you have a `step_definitions` directory inside your `features` directory?  And are your steps in that directory?

Comment: Yes I include step_definitions in Features directory

Answer (score 0):

You tell cucumber where to find the step definitions using the [glue](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-options/) option.

I noticed that you included the rubymine tag.  You can look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/creating-step-definition.html) for how rubymine handles step definitions.